# CSS, JQuery, HTML <p> not Seen on slideme class

Tags: jquery, css, html

View and Compile the code I cannot see p tag when clicked

HTML

Slide up/down

```
<div class="slideme" class="center">    
    <h1>Hello,</h1>
    <p>Can you see Me</p>
</div>

<button class="center"> Click Me </button>
```

CSS

```
body{background-color:yellow;}

.center{
position:relative;
margin:auto;
text-align:center;}


div{
border:20px solid #660000;
margin:-20px auto;
background-color:red;
color:white;
height:600px;
width:300px;
display:none;
line-height:500px;}

.large{
border:2px solid black;}

.small{
border:2px solid black;
color:orange;}


button{
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
cursor:pointer;
padding:3px 150px 3px 150px;
text-align:center;
border-radius:20px;
font-family:Times;}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("button").click(function() {
    $("div").slideToggle("slow");
});});
```

**On my file, when I run it and click on "click me" then it shows the "hello"
but "can you see me" is not shown**

Comment: I can see it. There's white text under the "Click Me" button. [(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/8vpv1a87/)

Comment: line-height:500px; - remove it and try then... you will need another method for vertical centering... http://jsfiddle.net/8vpv1a87/1/

Comment: Your HTML might be invalid. Not sure if you are allowed to have the `class` attribute twice.

Comment: yes @putvande we can use it twice or even thrice !! By that way we can do designing more effectively

Comment: No you can only use an attribute once per HTML element. Other will be ignored. See http://jsfiddle.net/72n7pu2b/1/ for example.

Comment: Ya you are correct, but can you tell me how did my slideme got on center !! ? actually, i am in doubt @putvande

Comment: `margin:-20px auto;` does that. Specifically the `auto` bit.  See http://jsfiddle.net/e743k3ru/ (commented out your `.center` CSS rules.

Comment: ya correct, i saw that, thanks!!  @putvande

Answer (score 0):

In your css, you just have to remove `line-height:500px;`

Like that :

```
div {
    border:20px solid #660000;
    margin:-20px auto;
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
    height:600px;
    width:300px;
    display:none;
    /*line-height:500px;*/
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zlen/8vpv1a87/2/) updated

Comment: Thanks Its Working !!!
but now the text is gone to top i want it at center of div

Answer (score 0):

Under `div` you have `line-height: 500px;`, that's pushing down the p tag. Change to `line-height: 1.3;` or whatever to fix.

Answer (score 0):

To get vertically centered text, in this case, you need to change HTML structure a bit. One method of vertical centering is using of `display:table`. So you have to do something like this in HTML:

```
<div class="slideme center"> 
    <div id="table">
    <div id="holder">
    <h1>Hello,</h1>
    <p>Can you see Me</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Note: i've used ids, for demo purposes, but you can easily change selectors later. If you have more elements like this one on page - css classes are the way to go.

CSS:

```
.slideme {
    border:20px solid #660000;
margin:-20px auto;
background-color:red;
color:white;
height:600px;

width:300px;
display:none;
}

#table {
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#holder {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

And your jQuery, same - with changed selector: (if you leave general `div` selector, you can get unexpected behavior, so, more specific, class selector should work fine)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("button").click(function() {
    $(".slideme").slideToggle("slow");
});});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8vpv1a87/3/

Explanation about line-height: This method works great when you have just one line of text, but if there are 2 or more lines - text is simple pushed down... This works for multi-line text/tags...

Comment: Thanks, i was not aware about it !

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the other answers, I think your way of doing it with `line-height:500px;` is OK. However, your problem can be solved by wrapping both `h1` and `p` in a container and then set the line height on that container to whatever you want.

HTML

```
<div class="slideme center">
  <spanclass="sub"> 
    <h1>Hello,</h1>
    <p>Can you see Me</p>
  </span>
</div>
<button class="center"> Click Me </button>
```

Add this to your CSS:

```
.sub {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 10px;   
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vpv1a87/4/)

Note: You should not have more that one `class` attribute. Notice how I merged your two classes in one `class` attribute separating them with a space like this: `<div class="slideme center">`.